# Android appWidget is possible set maxWidth in a widget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget

I'm developing an app android.
I've to do an appwidget that have to have 2 size : 2 column x 1 row & 1x1
my widget now is:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
android:minHeight="40dip"
android:minWidth="110dip"
android:resizeMode="none"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1000" />
```

i'd like do just one widget that can be resized but only to these widths so i tried to do

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
android:minHeight="40dip"
android:minWidth="40dip"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
android:resizeMode="horizontal"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1000" />
```

it's work..
but i've not found a way to set maxWidth!
how can i do it?